# Error installing Homebrew on macOS Sierra: The user "me" cannot be found

Tags: macos, homebrew, macos-sierra

I need to install homebrew but I get this after pasting the command

> The user "me" cannot be found
>
> There was an unknown error.
>
> This script requires the user “me” to be an Administrator. If this sucks for you then you can install Homebrew in your home directory or however you please; please refer to our homepage. If you still want to use this script set your user to be an Administrator in System Preferences or `su' to a non-root user with Administrator privileges.

I think it might have something to do with changing the name of my account / home directory a few months ago, but I followed all steps carefully. I really would like to avoid having to wipe everything.

I've tried using **su** and I get

> su: Sorry

I've tried using **sudo** and I get

> Don't run this as root!

*come on*

I've tried to work around it creating a new admin user and installing homebrew from there, and it works, but then I can't use it from the main user. Switching users all the time would be a pain. Any ideas?

**////EDIT**

My primary account is an admin account. It is the only account at the moment. When I use **id** I get 80(admin).

When I install from another admin account and then I try to use **brew** from my main account I get permission errors (can't paste them right now because I removed that installation) Should I install from a secondary account and then try to change permission of all homebrew folders and files to my main account? Does that make any sense? Would I be able to remove the dummy account later?

**////EDIT 2**

I still don't know what was wrong but I worked around it I guess?

I created a second admin account and installed homebrew, then used [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42127/homebrew-permissions-multiple-users-needing-to-brew-update) to change permissions of /usr/local and removed the new account.

Comment: If you've installed it with another Admin account, that should install it system-wide, and it should be available to all users.

Comment: It sounds like your primary account is not an admin account. Use your secondary/admin account to promote your primary account to an admin account via System Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, the problem was that I override the variable $USER inside my bash_profile, because of my customization in iTerm2.

Just enter inside your bash_profile:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

Or use your preffered terminal editor.

Search for $USER variable and delete the line.

Close and open a new terminal window.